# How do I open the native iOS maps app from a Visualforce page in Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, ios

I have a Visualforce page that displays Account addresses.  I would like to create a link to open the native iOS Maps app.  I've tried using the following and it doesn't appear to work:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1

```
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?q=cupertino">Cupertino</a>
```

<s>The link in my Visualforce page does nothing.</s>

UPDATE: I had poorly encoded data in the url string.  So now the link does open, however, it redirects to a google map.  Is there a way to launch the iOS app or at least prompt the user to allow it?

Comment: Can you show the link you're actually using?

Comment: I'm using the one in the example - `<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?q=cupertino">Cupertino</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way would be to use javascript. Then o'click determine how to proceed. Something like this will be your core javascript function. Note using the maps:// will open in iOS, then any other device would open on google maps.  Gives you the most flexibility and a fallback to Google Maps.

```
if( (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) 
    || (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1)
    || (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad") != -1))
     window.open("maps://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=lat,long&amp;ll=");
else
     window.open("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=lat,long&amp;ll=");
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe, someone has an equal case.
I have a visual force page, which is placed into a service in salesforce1 app in field service lightning where the user can click on the map to get guided to the address. I have adopted the javascript code here to visual force page this way:

```
if( navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1 
|| navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1
|| navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad") != -1){
    fullscreen = true;

  var navigatorWrap = document.createElement("div");
  navigatorWrap.style.position = "relative";
  navigatorWrap.style.top = "-33px";
  navigatorWrap.className = "pull-right";

  var button = document.createElement('a');
  button.className = "btn btn-sm btn-warning";
  button.innerHTML = "Navigate with Maps";
  button.href = "maps://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+serviceLat +","+ serviceLng +"&directionsmode=driving"
  navigatorWrap.appendChild(button);
  document.getElementById("wrap").appendChild(navigatorWrap);
 }
else {
fullscreen = true;

  var navigatorWrap = document.createElement("div");
  navigatorWrap.style.position = "relative";
  navigatorWrap.style.top = "-33px";
  navigatorWrap.className = "pull-right";

  var button = document.createElement('a');
  button.className = "btn btn-sm btn-warning";
  button.innerHTML = "Navigate with Maps";
  button.href = "https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+serviceLat +","+ serviceLng +"&directionsmode=driving"
  navigatorWrap.appendChild(button);
  document.getElementById("wrap").appendChild(navigatorWrap);

}
```

of course, there is a bit more in this page then that, but this might help for any of need for that.